# Keyboard and Trackpad Only working in Boot Device Selection and MacOS

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, startup, trackpad, dual-boot

The keyboard and trackpad for my Mac Book Pro 13" Retina Early 2015 (MacBookPro13,1) will only work in boot device selection (Holding down option on boot), MacOS (Running 10.14.6), Recovery, and Diagnostics.

The keyboard and trackpad *will not* work on any Linux Distrobution (Arch, Ubuntu, Fedora, DSL, TinyCore), Windows 10 Installer (Windows 10 for Workstations and Windows 10 Pro). But it will work in the bootloaders for the installers (Windows Bootloader, GRUB, and rEFInd)

I have done;

- Reset my PRAM/NVRAM
- Reset SMC
- Re-seated Trackpad to Logic Board Cable,
- Re-seated all cables on the trackpad control board

When I've booted into linux and my keyboard/trackpad don't work I've tried doing `lsusb -tv` the output for it is [on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yMHU4phh).

I cannot take the laptop to an Apple store because every problem I have they always suggest buying a new laptop, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Does the keyboard work for macOS?

Comment: This seems to be a software issue. I assume they keyboard and mouse work in macOS? There are a bunch of questions regarding issues with keyboard and mouse in the windows installer (https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=keyboard+windows+installer). Perhaps concentrate on one OS you want to install and either do that with external peripherals or specifically post a question for it (check if existing answers exist first).

Comment: It's not a software issue, well it shouldn't be. The keyboard is working on everything *except* 3rd party software. It works in macOS, all bootloaders, but not 3rd part operating systems. On linux i've even tried the MBPSPI Drivers and that still did not work. It was working previously on my linux install but one evening it just stopped working randomly. As said in the initial question i've replaceed the trackpad cable and reseated all cables to do with the keyboard/trackpad.